# Работа Box2D в Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, box2d

Я делаю игру с использованием `LevelHelper` (`SpriteKit` + `Box2D`) и столкнулся с проблемой.

`Box2D` зависит от количества FPS. Т.е. если в игре 60FPS, то тело двигается со скоростью 10 метров в секунду, если 30FPS, то со скоростью 5 метров в секунду.. надо что бы независимо от количества FPS была постоянная скорость.

Есть какое то решение что бы отвязать `Box2D` от количества FPS?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать зависимость скорости от FPS, и при проседании FPS увеличивать скорость на множитель

Comment: Это не подходит ибо нужна работа с постоянной скоростью не зависимо от FPS, и если менять step в зависимости от FPS, то Box2D начинает тупить и глючить) Нужно что бы на устройстве с 60FPS работало точно так же как и на устройстве с 10-20-30 FPS без погрешностей.. т.е. положено за 1 секунду пройти 10 метров, и за столько времени и пройдет, а не за 1.1 секунду или 1.05.. иначе говоря нужна полная синхронность)

Comment: Ну тогда даже не знаю